# ListBox Style Not Working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to get the highlight color of the selected items in my `ListBox` to stay the same when the `ListBox` loses focus. After hours scouring the internet and trying different solutions I can't get anything to work. Please help me understand why the solution I'm trying now doesn't seem to change anything.

This is defined at the top of my xaml within Window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="myListboxStyle">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

and this is my listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstNaes" Style="{StaticResource myListboxStyle}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5" SelectionMode="Extended"/>
```

The color (red) is just to test. What I really want is the default highlight color, and for it to not change when the `ListBox` (or `ListView`) loses focus. I don't understand why no solutions I've found seem to work for me.

Comment: I was sure the TargetType attribute (of Style element) was mandatory, but maybe I confuse with Xamarin Forms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on Windows 8 or later you should define a custom `ControlTemplate` for the `ListViewItem` containers:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstNaes" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#1F26A0DA"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#a826A0Da"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this working for a ListView as well? I tried replacing all ListBox with ListView, but my list shows up with a bunch of cryptic stuff. There are 2 columns in my ListView

Comment: @MatthewHagemann: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.